How do I find the init for an ubuntu installation that I just did
I ran the following command ps 1 to find out the init process running on the newly installed ubuntu on my system.ps 1 returned
PID TTY STAT TIME COMMAND 1 ? Sl 0:00 /init

For some reason it does not indicate that it is SysVinit,Upstart or Systemd. Not sure how to find that out so that I can use the right commands going forward.
Thanks
PID TTY STAT TIME COMMAND 1 ? Sl 0:00 /init

Also tried stat /init which returned /init

My Ubuntu installation does not have /init, but ls -l /sbin/init. Have you tried ls -l /sbin/init? In case it is a symbolic link, that might give you some insights.

@Hermann Thank you for your response.I ran the above command and I got :lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar 15  2023 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd

But now when I try to use systemd,I get the following message   "Trying to run as user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd".Is this because I used WSL to install Ubuntu from Windows 11 that some of the commands are not available?Not sure.

@KrishVenkat that's nonsensical; systemd's init runs, you don't have to start systemd anymore (you technically can't!). All the things systemd does on your system are available to you. Note that WSL is not a completely standalone linux, so thinking of the job of an init system, you don't use it for as many things :)

It is also noteworthy that while systemd is present in WSL Ubuntu, it is not necessarily in use, see https://superuser.com/questions/1785697/systemd-in-wsl-on-windows-11-is-not-working.

Ubuntu uses systemd for many years now. If you want to check this, many init systems set up symlinks to places like /init or /bin/init, so looking at the process command line is not always informative.
Here is a more reliable way:
#!/bin/sh

init_system=$(readlink -f /sbin/init)
case ${init_system##*/} in
    systemd) echo systemd ;;
    init) echo "SysVinit (probably)" ;;
    upstart) echo Upstart ;;
    runit-init) echo runit ;;
    openrc-init) echo OpenRC ;;
    *) echo "Unknown init system" ;;
esac


Ubuntu uses systemd; has been since Ubuntu 15.04, more than nine years ago. Upstart has been removed from Ubuntu since 16.10. Upstart had replaced sysvinit in 2006 for Ubuntu.
So, you have systemd.
Alternatively, you can just ask systemctl --version ;)

Thanks @Marcus Muller .I tried using systemctl --version and I got the following response:  "systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.21)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid"

as said, and as inherent on Ubuntu: this proves you have systemd.
